Calculate the substraction values fields of the nearest point between two points layers
In a heat island effect control project, I start from two point layers with the values of daytime and nighttime temperatures in degrees C:
'POINTS_DAY'
'POINTS_NIGHT'
These layers contain the "TEMP" field with the temperature values. I add an example screenshot:

I would like to calculate the temperature difference between Day and Night Temperature with the each nearest points where the measurements have been captured.
I use a Geometry Generator expression to visualize each nearest point of the POINTS_DAY layer to the POINTS_NIGHT layer by connecting the two points with a line. I achieve this with the following expression for Geometry Generator:
collect_geometries (
    array_foreach (
        overlay_nearest (
            'target_p', -- rename the layer if necessary
            $geometry,
            limit:=2
        ),
        make_line (
            $geometry,
            @element
        )
    )
)


My goal is to calculate the temperature substraction between each pair of nearby points, and fill the "DIFF" field of the POINTS_DAY layer with the substraction value.

We can do this with an update expression on the "DIFF" Field of the POINTS_DAY layer as follows:
TEMP - overlay_nearest(layer:='POINTS_NIGHT', expression:= TEMP, max_distance:= 500)[0]

i.e.
Temperature value [TEMP] for the current day point minus [-] the temperature value [TEMP] for the nearest night point ['POINTS_NIGHT'] within 500 metres/units.
You can change the 500 to increase the search areas for the closest point.


